# Variables not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run it I receive the outputs that *word* is not defined and that *game()* has an issue. Could I get some help?

```py
def game():
  word = input("Gimme a word: ")
  if word.isalpha():
    print("It's all letters")
    word = answer
  else:
    print('nope')
    game()

game()
print(answer)
```

Comment: Where is `answer` defined?  It looks like it's a global variable.  And why is `game()` calling itself recursively?  Recursion is the wrong construct for this.  Use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: if you run that code, it will give you a `NameError` for `answer` not being defined, and indeed it isn't. Not sure what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: Can you include the full error message with your question? This puts whatever you are seeing in far more context.

Comment: You're assigning the value of `answer` to `word` even though answer does not have any value. Is this the whole code or just a part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what do you want this code to do, so I'll assume that it will print the answer if you enter a string that only contained letters

```
answer = 'asdasdasdasdanswer'

def game():
  while True:
    word = input("Gimme a word: ")
    if word.isalpha():
      print("It's all letters")
      return answer
    else :
      print("nope")

print(game())
```

or if you want to edit the value of word

```
def game():
  while True:
    word = input("Gimme a word: ")
    if word.isalpha():
      print("It's all letters")
      return word
    else :
      print("nope")

answer = game()
#do something with answer
print(answer)
```

Comment: Thank you! I see where my issue was now. The second solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't have variable *answer*

So declare a global variable answer

```
answer = '' 
def game():
  word = input("Gimme a word: ")
  if word.isalpha():
    print("It's all letters")
    word = answer
  else:
    print('nope')
    game()

game()
print(answer)
```